# AttributeError in pygame

Tags: pygame

Here is where my error jumps onto the screen. With this message:
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_rect'
Because im trying to make a sprite

```
rigto = [pygame.image.load("img/Iconos/guy1.png"), pygame.image.load("img/Iconos/guy2.png"), pygame.image.load("img/Iconos/guy3.png"), pygame.image.load("img/Iconos/guy4.png")]

class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

jugador1 = Player(500, 500, rigto)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rigto` is a list of images (`pygame.Surface` objects). You have to choose one image:

e.g.:

```py
jugador1 = Player(500, 500, rigto[1])
```

---

Alternatively, you can manage the images in the class (e.g. for animations):

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, image_list):
        self.image_list = image_list
        self.count = 0

        self.image = self.image_list[self.count]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))

    def update(self)
        self.count += 1
        frame = self.count // 10
        if frame >= len(self.image_list):
            self.count = 0
            frame = 0
        self.image = self.image_list[frame]
```

```py
jugador1 = Player(500, 500, rigto)
```